# What are the bits in an IPv4 CIDR or even IP?

Tags: ip, 32-bit, ipv4, cidr

I am trying to understand the bits which are structured in an IPv4 or CIDR. Reading through RFC documentation I understood that the IP addresses began as 4 octets of made up of 32-bits. I am confused at what a network mask of 255.255.0.0 means?

Even more over if we look at an IP associated with cnn.com
151.101.65.67

Are the individual bits of the IP listed above
01101001.01000001.00110101.00110111
?

Or am I not thinking about this correctly. The network mask has 255.255.0.0 as an example but how would I look at the actuals bits represented in the octets?

Answer (score 0):

The IPv4 address 151.101.65.67 corresponds to the number that can be represented as hexadecimal 0x97654143 or decimal ‭2539995459‬. In binary it would be 0b‭10010111011001010100000101000011‬. It is shown as 151.101.65.67 for the sake of human readers (decimal 151 = hexadecimal 97 = binary ‭10010111‬, etc., notice that you can simply concatenate the hexadecimal or binary representations to form the full number, *but not the decimal*!)

A network mask determines which part of an IP address corresponds to the *network* and which part is a *host*. It "shows" the network part with a binary '1's and "hides" the client part with binary '0's.

The network mask is 'anded' to an IP address and results in the network address. In your example:

IP address (‭10010111011001010100000101000011) & mask (11111111111111110000000000000000)

is = 10010111011001010000000000000000, or 151.101.0.0

The network mask is usually *only relevant locally*. Consider a client with IP address 151.101.66.45 and network mask 255.255.255.0 that wants to view a page on your example IP.

The first decision the client needs to make is: can it connect to the address directly (i. e. is it in the same local network?) or does it need to send the request to the router (gateway). By "&"ing its own IP with **its own** newtwork mask (result = 151.101.66.0) and comparing it with the remote address & **its own** network mask (result = 151.101.65.0) it determines that both values are *not* equal, so the request goes to the router for further communication.

Comment: Firstly, thank you.I now better understand what you are explaining. I have continued reading documentation by RFC 4632, RFC 1878, Microsoft, and Amazon. Regarding IP I have not before seen "0b" as in your explanation 0b10010111011001010100000101000011, I am not sure the significance of "0b"? Also, IP or IPv4 initially describes a network and host in 4 bytes, right? For example, network.network.nework.host ? Regarding configuration of a server for a secure connection over port 22. The IPv4 configuration is host’s computer local IP, or public IP, or routers IP / [CIDR 32] or 255.255.255.255?

Comment: What is the difference in between the local IPv4 address of a computer and the public IPv4 address of a computer? Is it misconception that I have always considered an IP address as a unique identifier to a computer. Upon reading documentation DHCP servers assign dynamic IPv4 address to devices such as servers, smartphones, and desktops so that they can communicate on networks per TCP/IP. I previously thought these devices came fresh out the box with an IP number, which is seemingly untrue. I'm having trouble locating my public IPv4 address on mac? Although I located the router and local IP.

Comment: The "0b" was just to indicate that the numbers are binary. An IP address is just a number. The collection of all numbers is (logically) divided into networks, and within a network into hosts, so you should think network.host. The IP address of a host must be unique _within_ a network. Most home networks will use IP addresses starting with 192.168. The _router_ will have a public (i. e. worldwide unique address) that is used (through NAT) to provide internet access to all host on you network. Your Pc is not aware of this address.